# How to boot Linux kernel from u-boot?

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot

My Linux kernel image `uImage` is in my U-disk. And I want to boot it from U-Boot. Also the device tree file `am335x-evm.dtb` is in my U-disk.
What I did is below:

```
U-Boot# usb start
(Re)start USB...
USB0:   scanning bus 0 for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found
       scanning usb for storage devices... 1 Storage Device(s) found
U-Boot# fatls usb 0:1
  3821960   uimage
            kit3/
  4065280   modules.tar
            my_modules/
            extra/
            system volume information/
      375   uenv.txt
    40474   am335x-evm.dtb

4 file(s), 4 dir(s)

U-Boot# fatload usb 0:1 0xC0700000 uImage
reading uImage
3821960 bytes read in 2375 ms (1.5 MiB/s)
U-Boot# fatload usb 0:1 0xC0e00000 am335x-evm.dtb
reading am335x-evm.dtb
40474 bytes read in 48 ms (823.2 KiB/s)
U-Boot# bootm 0xC0700000 - 0xC0e00000
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at c0700000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.12.10-ge35dc10-dirty
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3821896 Bytes = 3.6 MiB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at c0e00000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0xc0e00000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK
   Using Device Tree in place at c0e00000, end c0e0ce19

Starting kernel ...
```

And it stops here. How to do? Thanks!

**Result:**
Thanks for everyone who answered in this post! Now I can boot the system by using the image in U-disk. What I do is:

```
setenv bootargs "console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext4 mem=512M coherent_pool=8M loglevel=0 lpj=3317760 rootwait"
usb start; fatls usb 0:1; fatload usb 0:1 0x82000000 uImage-orig-onUSB;fatload usb 0:1 0x80F80000 am335x-evm.dtb;bootm 0x82000000 - 0x80F80000
```

Without the first sentence, the system can also boot and start the GUI program which will show in a display. But the debug serial port has no reaction any more!

As for the second sentence, if I use the ram address of 0xC0700000 and 0xC0e00000, like this below, then it will stop to load the kernel. The reason should be what sawdust mentioned in his answer. @sawdust

```
setenv bootargs "console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext4 mem=512M coherent_pool=8M loglevel=0 lpj=3317760 rootwait"
usb start; fatls usb 0:1; fatload usb 0:1 0xC0700000 uImage-orig-onUSB;fatload usb 0:1 0xC0e00000 am335x-evm.dtb;bootm 0xC0700000 - 0xC0e00000
```

Comment: Enable `EARLY_PRINTK` in kernel (and corresponding UART option). Also pass `earlyprintk` to cmdline via `bootargs` variable. This way you will see what is going wrong. Also check your `console` param in `bootargs` (and `CMDLINE` option in kernel): it may be that you just use wrong `/dev/tty...` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the message *"Starting kernel ..."*, the kernel has not actually started executing (because the image has to be first relocated and also uncompressed), and consequently enabling **earlyprintk** will have no effect yet.
What does look suspect are the RAM addresses.

The typical "am33xx-evm" board only has 512MB of RAM starting at 0x80000000.
  Yet you are trying to use RAM addresses from 0xC0700000 to 0xC0E0CE19 where physical memory should not exist.
  Obviously the kernel and the device tree are *not* loaded properly.

Instead of

```
fatload usb 0:1 0xC0700000 uImage
fatload usb 0:1 0xC0e00000 am335x-evm.dtb
bootm 0xC0700000 - 0xC0e00000
```

try using

```
fatload usb 0:1 0x80200000 uImage 
fatload usb 0:1 0x80e00000 am335x-evm.dtb
bootm 0x80200000 - 0x80e00000
```

Comment: I would agree on the RAM range part, but then it's strange it is saying the Checksum is OK. I think the OP should verbose on the platform he is using. As for the other, the image is uncompressed already, and we don't usually get any messages about the relocation process.

Comment: @EugeneSh. *"it is saying the Checksum is OK"* -- There may be address wrapping going on.  *"image is uncompressed already"* -- Not necessarily: the most common ARM kernel image to use in uImage is a zImage, which is self-decompessing and U-Boot always reports it as *"uncompressed"*.  BTW *"verbose"* is not a verb.

Comment: So if the wrapping is taking place and the checksum is calculated, isn't it meaning that the image is fully in the memory somewhere? Sorry about wrong English usage.

Comment: Actually I have a beagle bone somewhere around, can try it out with a working kernel..

Answer (score 2):

The booting sequence looks fine. The kernel and the device tree are loaded properly. The problem seems to be in the kernel itself. Probably it is just not built with the right settings. Specifically the console device and early `printk` facility should be enabled. Also check your `bootargs`.